# Unable to insert COPY_SEND when programatically calling VC in Notification Content Extension

Tags: ios, swift, usernotifications

After creating a Notification Content Extension and then removing the
NSExtensionMainStoryboard and replacing it with NSExtensionPrincipalClass in the info.plist file and calling the module.viewController appropriately and then debug the extension I see the following error?

NotificationExtension[58062:21665141] [Common] _BSMachError: port 5c03; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"

below is the NotificationExtensionViewControllerCode

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import UserNotificationsUI

class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, UNNotificationContentExtension {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any required interface initialization here.
    }

    func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {

    }

}
```

What is causing the error and how do I go about resolving it?

If you do the same above but use the NSExtensionMainStoryboard calling the storyboard but delete the label you get the same error!

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` on the attachment url (in `didReceive`). Some genius at Apple decided that it's dangerous for a notification extension to just access the file in the **notification storage**. Of course it's well documented (NOT!)

```
if let attachment = notification.request.content.attachments.first {
    if attachment.url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: attachment.url.path) as? Data {
            self.uiImage.image = UIImage(data: data) // <- that's the image view
            attachment.url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        }
    }
}
```